# data binding framework zk

Tags: java, zk

I am intenting do a login with zk framework and my view is:

```
<zk xmlns:h="xhtml" xmlns:w="client">

<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
     form="@id('fx') @load(vm.selected) @save(vm.selected, before='update') @validator('com.java2eehub.FormValidator',retypedPassword=vm.retypedPassword)">
    <grid>
        <rows>
            <row>email<textbox value="@bind(fx.email)" /></row>
            <row>password<textbox value="@bind(fx.password)" type="password"/></row>
            <row>retype password<textbox value="@bind(fx.retypePassword)" type="password"/></row>
            <row>
                <cell colspan="3" style="text-align:center">
                    <vlayout>
                        <label visible="@load(empty vmsgs)"
                               value="@load(empty vmsgs ? 'Form successfully submitted!' : '', before='submit')" />
                        <button label="Submit" onClick="@command('submit')"
                                width="100px" height="30px" />
                    </vlayout>
                </cell>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </grid>
</div>
</zk>
```

and i have a java class to validate the data:

```
package com.java2eehub;
import java.util.Map;

import org.zkoss.bind.Property;
import org.zkoss.bind.ValidationContext;
import org.zkoss.bind.validator.AbstractValidator;

public class FormValidator extends AbstractValidator {

public void validate(ValidationContext ctx) {
    //all the bean properties
    Map<String,Property> beanProps = ctx.getProperties(ctx.getProperty().getBase());
    //first let's check the passwords match
    validatePasswords(ctx, (String)beanProps.get("password").getValue(), (String)ctx.getValidatorArg("retypedPassword"));
    validateEmail(ctx, (String)beanProps.get("email").getValue());
}

private void validatePasswords(ValidationContext ctx, String password, String retype) { 
    if(password == null || retype == null || (!password.equals(retype))) {
        this.addInvalidMessage(ctx, "password", "Your passwords do not match!");
    }
}


private void validateEmail(ValidationContext ctx, String email) {
    if(email == null || !email.matches(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+")) {
        this.addInvalidMessage(ctx, "email", "Please enter a valid email!");            
    }
}

}
```

i do not have a view model because:, Why i need a MainVIewModel?, i need only do a validation between password and re-password, and email, What would be the mainviewmodel  in this case?

and without  `viewModel="@id('vm') @init('foo.MainViewModel')"`  i run the login i have the folloging error:

`org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: Objetivo inalcanzable, identificador 'vm' resuelto a nulo at`

Who can say me, what is my mistake and how can i solve my problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You did not init vm. You need to do something like.

```
   <div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('foo.MainViewModel')" >
```

### Edit

You need this because here

```
@load(vm.selected)
```

you access `vm` without initialization, so zk don't know what `vm` is.
So what should zk load or save? What is `vm.selected`?

Comment: Why i need a MainVIewModel?, i need only do a validation between password and re-password, and What would be the mainviewmodel  in this case?

Comment: you need to add a ViewModel for the binding `vm.selected`.